# SharedPreferences doesnt work with setTextSize

Tags: java, android

Hello i want to implement different text sizes for my app i tried with sharedpreferences here's my code

Declaring SharedPreferences

```
final  SharedPreferences savedFields;

    savedFields = this.getSharedPreferences("stoixeiaios", 0);
    stoixeia.setText(savedFields.getString("stoixeiadieth", ""));
    stoixeia2.setText(savedFields.getString("stoixeiaonoma", ""));

    logos1.setTextSize(savedFields.getFloat("megethos1",12));
    logos2.setTextSize(savedFields.getFloat("megethos2",12));
    logos3.setTextSize(savedFields.getFloat("megethos3",12));
    logos4.setTextSize(savedFields.getFloat("megethos4",12));
    logos5.setTextSize(savedFields.getFloat("megethos5",12));
    logos6.setTextSize(savedFields.getFloat("megethos6",12));
```

The button which changes the text size and saves the value to sharedpreferences

```
**    button4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = savedFields.edit();
                logos1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,24));
                logos2.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,24);
                logos3.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,24);
                logos4.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,24);
                logos5.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,24);
                logos6.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,24);


                preferencesEditor.putFloat("megethos1", logos1.getTextSize());
                preferencesEditor.putFloat("megethos2", logos2.getTextSize());
                preferencesEditor.putFloat("megethos3", logos3.getTextSize());
                preferencesEditor.putFloat("megethos4", logos4.getTextSize());
                preferencesEditor.putFloat("megethos5", logos5.getTextSize());
                preferencesEditor.putFloat("megethos6", logos6.getTextSize());

                preferencesEditor.commit();
            }
        });**
```

I don't know what i am doing wrong

Thank you for your time

Edit : I forgot to post the problem

The problem is that the saved values after the app terminates are ALWAYS wrong
for example when i click the button to change the text size , the text size changes then i terminate the app reopen it and the text size is bigger than it's supposed to be

Comment: What is the actual error? Are the values not saving?

Comment: Im sorry you are right 

The problem is that the saved values after the app terminates are ALWAYS wrong
for example when i click the button to change the text size , the text size changes then i terminate the app reopen it and the text size is bigger than it's supposed to be

Comment: If you have the default textsize as 12 and then you set them to 24, then I expect the values to be set to 24 when the app is reopened since they have been saved as 24 in the `setOnClickListener()` for the button.

Comment: When i reopen the app the values are set higher maybe 30 or 34 definitely not 24 though 
Edit : I have another button which sets the text size to 10 but when i reopen the app it goes higher than 10  maybe 15 or 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the text size in pixels.
What you need to do is to convert it into density pixels.

To do this you can use this method

```
public int pxToDp(float px) {
    return (int) (px / Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}
```

So when you set the text size you should call

```
float textSize = savedFields.getFloat("megethos1",12);
logos1.setTextSize(pxToDp(textSize));
```

for every TextView.